# override inline css with jquery and/or css

Tags: jquery, css

How do I remove the font size and the bold code with jquery and/or css. I tried a variety of methods but cannot seem to get it.

I tried adding a class and then styling it via css and !important but that only worked if I put font-weight:lighter, I cannot seem to override the inline css so I said why not simply remove it.

The selector I have to add the class is

```
$("td[width='6%'][valign='CENTER']").addClass('quantity_box')
```

Here is the code ( I do not have access to it)

```
<td width="6%" valign="CENTER" bgcolor="#f9f9f9"><font size="4"><b>2</b></font>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding more specific CSS rules to target both the `font` and `b` tags will allow you to override the inline styles. Set the values to your appropriate values.

```
.quantity_box font { font-size: 10px; }
.quantity_box font b { font-weight: normal; }
```

Comment: LOL I wasn't targeting the font/b tag directly in css. Was targeting just the .quantity_box class and not .quantity_box font/b class, I feel stupid now, thx for the wake up call!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("b").remove(":contains('2')");
```

Comment: This is way too broad and will not work with other content on the page